# Get Layout Name from View in MVC5

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to get the Layout name a View is using through Razor, ViewBag, or something else?

I found this article, but not exactly what I am looking for:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/3WDE140613-Different-ways-of-rendering-layouts-in-Asp.Net-MVC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Layout is set inside a view using the `Layout` property have you tried just reading that value in your view?

IE: `<div>@Layout</div>`